# c# datagridview winforms разрешить вставать на ячейку и запретить входить внутрь этой ячейки

Tags: c#, winforms

Как можно разрешить вставать на ячейку и запретить входить внутрь  ячеек в datagridview. И при этом ячейки должны редактироваться. То есть ячейки должны редактироваться снаружи а не из внутри.Спасибо!!

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто. Установите значение свойства `ReadOnly=true` в конструкторе формы.
Или в самой программе `dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;`
Тогда изменять значения программным путем будет возможно по прежнему, однако пользователь ничего изменить внутри dataGridView не сможет.